# Keras. Weight of base model is set to 'None', but there's an error

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

The code:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

base_model = MobileNetV2(
    include_top=False, 
    input_shape=(100, 100, 3),
    weights="None",
)

layer = Dense(256, activation='relu')(base_model.output)
out = Dense(28)(layer)

model = Model(base_model.input, out)
```

And this code causes an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-190-5cf5e34e46ca> in <module>
      9     include_top=False,
     10     input_shape=(128, 128, 3),
---> 11     weights="None",
     12 )
     13 

ValueError: The `weights` argument should be either `None` (random initialization), `imagenet` (pre-training on ImageNet), or the path to the weights file to be loaded.
```

As you see the `weights` is already set to `'None'`, but for some reason this error is not dissappearing. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drop the double quotes of `None`:

```
base_model = MobileNetV2(
    include_top=False, 
    input_shape=(100, 100, 3),
    weights=None
)
```